Can't get Hetzner CI/CD deployment working - what machines are available? Is there some other issue?
TL;DR: I can't seem to find working CX22s/32s or CAX11s/21s anywhere. What machine + location combinations are actually available currently? Or do I have some other problem?
Main issue:
I am a beginner with Hetzner, cloud stuff, setting up CI/CD pipelines, and devops stuff in general - I've mostly stuck to the coding side of things up till now.
I am trying to get a pipeline setup hosted on Hetzner based on Kube-Hetzner (https://github.com/kube-hetzner/terraform-hcloud-kube-hetzner). I followed the instructions and everything worked until I got to terraform apply -auto-approve. I got errors along these lines:
 │ Error: error during placement (resource_unavailable, 648ec35b31aeacc7)
 │
 │   with module.kube-hetzner.module.control_planes["0-0-control-plane-sin"].hcloud_server.server,
 │   on .terraform\modules\kube-hetzner\modules\host\main.tf line 22, in resource "hcloud_server" "server":
 │   22: resource "hcloud_server" "server" {

Resources I found online seemed to imply the issue was a shortage of certain machines at certain locations, particularly CXs. I tried switching to equivalent CAXs and trying different locations without luck. I also reached out to Hetzner support, who pointed me to this status page (https://status.hetzner.com/incident/aa5ce33b-faa5-4fd0-9782-fde43cd270cf) about the shortage, and told me to try different locations/machines or try again later.
I tried some of the combinations not listed on that shortage list, and it still didn't work. Basically got response from Hetzner saying other things might also be in shortage and to again try different combinations or try later.
I can't just try every single possible permutation of machine types and locations. Are there any boxes available??? Or am I running into some other issue that is masquerading as a machine shortage?
More info: I am using Windows. Had some slight hiccups adapting the Kube-Hetzner instructions, but ultimately seemed to get everything working fine up to this point. Redacted version of my kube.tf, showing original use of CX22 + CX32 at location ash and region us-east (with sensitive info and comments removed):
locals {
  
  hcloud_token = "<my_token_here>"
}

module "kube-hetzner" {
  providers = {
    hcloud = hcloud
  }
  hcloud_token = var.hcloud_token != "" ? var.hcloud_token : local.hcloud_token

  source = "kube-hetzner/kube-hetzner/hcloud"

  control_plane_nodepools = [
    {
      name        = "control-plane-ash",
      server_type = "cx22",
      location    = "ash",
      labels      = [],
      taints      = [],
      count       = 1
    },
    {
      name        = "control-plane-ash-2",
      server_type = "cx22",
      location    = "ash",
      labels      = [],
      taints      = [],
      count       = 1
    },
    {
      name        = "control-plane-ash-3",
      server_type = "cx22",
      location    = "ash",
      labels      = [],
      taints      = [],
      count       = 1
    }
  ]

  agent_nodepools = [
    {
      name        = "agent-small",
      server_type = "cx22",
      location    = "ash",
      labels      = [],
      taints      = [],
      count       = 1
    },
    {
      name        = "agent-large",
      server_type = "cx32",
      location    = "ash",
      labels      = [],
      taints      = [],
      count       = 1
    },
    {
      name        = "storage",
      server_type = "cx32",
      location    = "ash",
      labels      = [
        "node.kubernetes.io/server-usage=storage"
      ],
      taints      = [],
      count       = 1
    },
    {
      name        = "egress",
      server_type = "cx22",
      location    = "ash",
      labels = [
        "node.kubernetes.io/role=egress"
      ],
      taints = [
        "node.kubernetes.io/role=egress:NoSchedule"
      ],
      floating_ip = true
      count = 1
    },
    {
      name        = "agent-arm-small",
      server_type = "cax11",
      location    = "ash",
      labels      = [],
      taints      = [],
      count       = 1
    },
    {
      name        = "agent-arm-small-2",
      server_type = "cax11",
      location    = "ash",
      labels      = [],
      taints      = [],
      nodes = {
        "1" : {
          location                  = "ash"
          labels = [
            "testing-labels=a1",
          ]
        },
        "20" : {
          labels = [
            "testing-labels=b1",
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  ]
  
  load_balancer_type     = "lb11"
  load_balancer_location = "ash"

  system_upgrade_use_drain = true

  dns_servers = [
    "1.1.1.1",
    "8.8.8.8",
    "2606:4700:4700::1111",
  ]
}

provider "hcloud" {
  token = var.hcloud_token != "" ? var.hcloud_token : local.hcloud_token
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.5.0"
  required_providers {
    hcloud = {
      source  = "hetznercloud/hcloud"
      version = ">= 1.43.0"
    }
  }
}

output "kubeconfig" {
  value     = module.kube-hetzner.kubeconfig
  sensitive = true
}

variable "hcloud_token" {
  sensitive = true
  default   = ""
}

